# Find next unused ID in table SQL which has non continous ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, range, nextval

I have two tables like the following:

```
TABLE1:
=======
somid, tobeupdated
1    ,  null
2    ,  null
3    ,  null
10   ,  null

TABLE2:
=======
rangeofids
2
3
9
10
11
12
13
```

I have to update TABLE1.tobeupdated (or found its' should be value) based on the following criteria(s):

1. if `TABLE1.somid NOT exists in TABLE2.rangeofids`, then the expected result is: tobeupdated = `TABLE1.somid`
2. else find the next available (or unused) `TABLE2.rangeofids` which is larger then `TABLE1.somid`

So the expected values are:bu

```
TABLE1:
=======
somid, tobeupdated
1    ,  1
2    ,  4
3    ,  4
10   ,  14
```

I tried hard, but the simplest solution I came up with is creating a temporary table with a full sequence of ids (from `1` to `max(rangeofids)+1`) `MINUS TABLE2.rangeofids` so I can found the `MIN(TMPTABLE.id) where TMPTABLE.ID > TABLE1.somid`.

But isn't there a better solution (without the temp table)?

*Note*: I can't create procedures/functions, etc, so it must be standard (Oracle 10) SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my try.

First we should decide using  only table2 what value should return after finding the value there.

```
select rangeofids, 
  candidate, 
  nvl(candidate,lead(candidate ignore nulls) over (order by rangeofids)) as full_candidate
from (
    select rangeofids, case when dist=1 then null else rangeofids+1 end as candidate
    from (
        select rangeofids,
               lead(rangeofids) over (order by rangeofids) - rangeofids as dist
        from table2
        )
      );
```

After this a `merge into table1 with` the below select will solve the problem:

```
select someid, nvl(full_candidate, someid) 
from table1 a
left join (    
    --the above query
) b
on a.someid = b.rangeofids;
```

[See SQLFIDDLE.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04540/15)